# Long delay in displaying screen swift 2.2

Tags: ios, uitableview, hidden

My application reads data from MySql server and displays it in a tableview. At the start of the call to the server the application covers the tableView with a view (named "pdView") that has background colour of Light Gray. That view is part of the scene which the tableView is also part of (designed in IB), but is in a hidden state, until just before the call to the server where it becomes visible using

```
    pdView.hidden = false
```

After the app gets the data and fills the tableview, using

```
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
         tableview.reloadData()
     })
```

one can see the data displayed in the tableView, under the gray display.
I then try to hide back the view using

```
    pdView.hidden = true
```

but it takes the app about 44 seconds for the gray color to disappear. During that time my app behaves normally and I can scroll the table up and down.

I tried putting the code to hide the view inside dispatch_async() but to no avail.

What needs to be done to fix this problem so that the pdView disappear right after it is back to the hidden state?

Comment: What if you hide it immediately after the call to `reloadData()`?

Comment: I tried that too - did not help

Comment: I'd like to know why someone downvoted the question without explanation.

Comment: I tried to duplicate the problem on a small plain application. What I have found out is that if I try to do 'pdView.hidden = true' not inside dispatch_sync() I do get the delay but also an error message in the debug window that says: " This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.".

But in my application I do not get this message, which means that I do it inside the dispatch_sync() function.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to update the UI from a separate thread. You will need to give your `pdView.hidden = true` some context. You can try

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    tableview.reloadData()
    self.pdView.hidden = true
})
```

Note the `self` in `self.pdView.hidden..`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**ALL** your UI code needs to be from the main thread. That includes things like changing the state of a view's `hidden` flag.

Do you have that code wrapped in a call to

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

as well?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned it in my description

Comment: Your description doesn't provide any info about the context in which you execute the `pdView.hidden = false` and  `pdView.hidden = true` statements. You need to edit your question to provide the complete code for your methods, along with more context.